# Why is the Context of another Model not working in Template

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-templates

I am have a project where Users have

1. Items (for images)
2. Posts (for articles)

Which are 2 separate apps, in the Home template I have a list view of the items only and I am trying to include the Post as well

Here is the model for the items (which is for images) :

```
class Item(models.Model):
    designer = models.ForeignKey(
        User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

Here is the views.py

```
class HomeView(ListView):
    model = Item
    template_name = "home.html"
    ordering = ['-timestamp']
```

Here is the Urls.py

```
app_name = 'core'

urlpatterns = [
    path('', HomeView.as_view(), name='home'),
```

I am trying to add the Context of Post so that I can include it in the HomeView

Here is the model for posts (which is for articles)

```
class Post(models.Model):
    designer = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

Here is the urls.py

```
app_name = 'score'

urlpatterns = [
    path('user/<str:username>', UserPostListView.as_view(), name='user-posts'),
```

What I am trying to do is in the Home page list the items and add a condition that if the user has a post the button appears and if the user has no posts it shows nothing.

Here is the template home

```
<a href="{% url 'core:designer-posts' item.designer.username %}">
<button style="margin-top: 10px;text-transform: none;" button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm btn-block">
Check all my products </button>
</a>
{% if posts %}
<a href="{% url 'score:user-posts' post.designer.username %}">
<button style="margin-top: 10px;text-transform: none;" button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-sm btn-block">
Check my posts</button>
</a>
{% else %}
Show Nothing
{% endif %}
```

Here is what I have tried but didn't succeed regarding the views.py for core app

```
class HomeView(ListView):
    model = Item
    template_name = "home.html"
    ordering = ['-timestamp']

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(HomeView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['posts'] = Post.objects.all()
        return context
```

I am not getting any errors the only thing that is happening is the `Show nothing` while it is suppost to show the button for `Check my Posts`

Comment: I don't understand your logic. Even if it worked, `Post.objects.all()` would return all `Post`s, not only the current user's posts.

Answer (score 0):

After understanding your question on my answer comments, you don't have to give any context data. What you need to do is do the url like this and that's it. you can now delete the context data.

```
<a href="{% url 'score:user-posts' request.user.username %}">
```

Comment: Great this is right it works but it is showing the button = to the number of posts I just want to show one button

Comment: also there are users who have no posts but the button is still showing while it shouldn't

Comment: that's because what you want is not to show each post here right? you want to show a view with the list of all the posts. Is that true? can you clarify what you really need to view and happen on your view? I don't understand your logic

Comment: what I want to do is show the button which is linking to another page with the designer's posts (in the `a href`) **only** when the designer has posts, if there is no posts related to the designer the button doesn't appear Shows Nothing

Comment: @AhmedKhairy I changed my question. is much easier